# Problema ao acessar um atributo inserido dinamicamente em um objeto "pronto" do Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize-js

Em uma certa parte do meu código eu tenho que setar esse campo/atributo (`actualValue`) em um objeto vindo do Sequelize (não posso armazenar o campo no banco), porém na hora de fazer o meu `if` não consigo acessar diretamente o atributo como faço com o `id`, `goal` e `state`.

Tem algum motivo plausível para isso acontecer ou alguma técnica para burlar isso e deixar o código mais padronizado ?

```
const value = await movementsController.getSumMovs('F',fund.id);
fund.setDataValue('actualValue',value); 
//Funciona apenas se eu chamar fund.dataValues.actualValue
if (fund.actualValue >= fund.goal && fund.state !== 'C') await completeGoal(fund.id);
```

Objeto `fund` completo:

```
Fund {
  dataValues: {
    id: '8ce36534-8ead-4662-ab89-f57137a5cd7c',
    description: 'Descrição do UPDATE',
    goal: 6.5,
    state: 'C',
    createdAt: 2021-05-14T00:06:01.777Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-05-18T21:56:21.467Z,
    actualValue: 16.01
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: '8ce36534-8ead-4662-ab89-f57137a5cd7c',
    description: 'Descrição do UPDATE',
    goal: 6.5,
    state: 'C',
    createdAt: 2021-05-14T00:06:01.777Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-05-18T21:56:21.467Z
  },
  _changed: Set(1) { 'actualValue' },
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [ 'id', 'description', 'goal', 'state', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt' ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

Comment: _"//Funciona apenas se eu chamar fund.dataValues.actualValue"_ se funciona assim, porque não usa desta forma?

Answer (score 0):

No caso, você tem um objeto chamado Fund, para setar o valor basta fazer isso:

```
var fund = { ... }
fund.dataValues.actualValue = value;
```